# back to top button icon not visible

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, elementor

https://techiesays.io/ This is the website I created. On this website, I added the back-to-top button[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1kwH.png). But the icon middle in that button is not visible on a specific page. I tried to change the CSS in inspecting it's working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdqFI.png)
https://techiesays.io/personal/ in this page it is not visible

Current css

```
scroll-btn i {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--theme-color);
  color: var(--white-color);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: var(--btn-size, 50px);
  height: var(--btn-size, 50px);
  line-height: var(--btn-size, 50px);
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: inherit;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo. All code should be included in the question instead of through an outside source.

Comment: Its working fine for me. Just logout and check.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following might work I am new to this business

```
    color: var(--white-color) 
    !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

worked after adding this css in the elementor custom css section